# How do I properly set up a scrolling NSTableView using Auto Layout? What I've tried has odd glitches

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I am trying to use [Auto Layout to set up scrolling in NSScrollView](http://blog.bjhomer.com/2014/08/nsscrollview-and-autolayout.html) to scroll a view-based NSTableView. I have a few issues.

The most obvious is: if all the rows are visible, the table can still be scrolled down by one row. For instance, take these before and after shots of the program at the end of this post:

[image: Before]
[image: After]

I am guessing that the NSTableHeaderView is overlapping the NSTableView, but I tried adding constraints that set the top of the NSTableView's NSClipView to both the bottom of the header view and its superview (another NSClipView, according to experiments). That didn't change anything; it seems as if the constraints are simply ignored.

Resizing the window as small as possible seems to push that first row out of the view as well, producing the second image when you grow the window again.

Horizontal scrolling also doesn't work or is very glitchy, but I'm wondering if that's due to column autoresizing.

This is on OS X 10.11, but has to work as far back as 10.8. **This is NOT iOS.**

Thanks!

```
// 22 june 2016
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NSLayoutConstraint *mkConstraint(id view1, NSLayoutAttribute attr1, NSLayoutRelation relation, id view2, NSLayoutAttribute attr2, CGFloat multiplier, CGFloat c)
{
    return [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
        attribute:attr1
        relatedBy:relation
        toItem:view2
        attribute:attr2
        multiplier:multiplier
        constant:c];
}

@interface tableModel : NSObject<NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation tableModel

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv
{
    return 15;
}

 - (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)table viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)c row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTableCellView *tv;
    NSTextField *tf;

    tv = [[NSTableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

    tf = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [tf setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", ((int) (row + 1))]];
    [tf setEditable:NO];
    [tf setSelectable:NO];
    [tf setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [tf setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSRegularControlSize]]];
    [tf setBordered:NO];
    [tf setBezelStyle:NSTextFieldSquareBezel];
    [tf setBezeled:NO];
    [[tf cell] setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
    [[tf cell] setScrollable:YES];

    [tf setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [tv addSubview:tf];
    [tv addConstraint:mkConstraint(tv, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        tf, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        1, -2)];
    [tv addConstraint:mkConstraint(tv, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        tf, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        1, 3)];
    [tv addConstraint:mkConstraint(tv, NSLayoutAttributeCenterY,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        tf, NSLayoutAttributeCenterY,
        1, 0)];

    [tv setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    return tv;
}

@end

NSTableColumn *mkColumn(NSString *title)
{
    NSTableColumn *c;

    c = [[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@""];
    // via Interface Builder
    [c setResizingMask:(NSTableColumnAutoresizingMask | NSTableColumnUserResizingMask)];
    [c setTitle:title];
    [[c headerCell] setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSSmallControlSize]]];
    return c;
}

NSTableView *mkTableView(void)
{
    NSTableView *tv;
    tableModel *model;

    tv = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

    model = [tableModel new];
    [tv setDataSource:model];
    [tv setDelegate:model];
    [tv reloadData];

    [tv setAllowsColumnReordering:NO];
    [tv setAllowsColumnResizing:YES];
    [tv setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [tv setAllowsEmptySelection:YES];
    [tv setAllowsColumnSelection:NO];
    [tv setUsesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors:YES];
    [tv setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular];
    [tv setGridStyleMask:NSTableViewGridNone];
    [tv setAllowsTypeSelect:YES];

    // needed to allow the table to grow vertically beyond showing all rows
    [tv setContentHuggingPriority:NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical];

    return tv;
}

NSScrollView *mkScrollView(NSView *dv)
{
    NSScrollView *sv;
    NSView *cv;

    sv = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    [sv setBackgroundColor:[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [sv setDrawsBackground:YES];
    [sv setBorderType:NSBezelBorder];
    [sv setAutohidesScrollers:YES];
    [sv setHasHorizontalRuler:NO];
    [sv setHasVerticalRuler:NO];
    [sv setRulersVisible:NO];
    [sv setScrollerKnobStyle:NSScrollerKnobStyleDefault];
    [sv setScrollsDynamically:YES];
    [sv setFindBarPosition:NSScrollViewFindBarPositionAboveContent];
    [sv setUsesPredominantAxisScrolling:NO];
    [sv setHorizontalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityAutomatic];
    [sv setVerticalScrollElasticity:NSScrollElasticityAutomatic];
    [sv setAllowsMagnification:NO];

    [dv setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [sv setDocumentView:dv];

    cv = [sv contentView];
    [sv addConstraint:mkConstraint(dv, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        cv, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        1, 0)];
    [sv addConstraint:mkConstraint(dv, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        cv, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
        1, 0)];
    [sv addConstraint:mkConstraint(dv, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual,
        cv, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        1, 0)];
    [sv addConstraint:mkConstraint(dv, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual,
        cv, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        1, 0)];

    return sv;
}

@interface appDelegate : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate>
@end

@implementation appDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSWindow *w;
    NSView *contentView;
    NSTableView *tv;
    NSScrollView *sv;

    w = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 320, 240)
        styleMask:(NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask)
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
        defer:YES];
    contentView = [w contentView];

    tv = mkTableView();
    [tv addTableColumn:mkColumn(@"Column")];
    sv = mkScrollView(tv);
    [sv setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [contentView addSubview:sv];

    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        sv, NSLayoutAttributeLeading,
        1, -20)];
    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        sv, NSLayoutAttributeTop,
        1, -20)];
    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        sv, NSLayoutAttributeTrailing,
        1, 20)];
    [contentView addConstraint:mkConstraint(contentView, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        sv, NSLayoutAttributeBottom,
        1, 20)];

    [w makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
}

- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)app
{
    return YES;
}

@end

int main(void)
{
    NSApplication *app;

    app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    [app setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
    [app setDelegate:[appDelegate new]];
    [app run];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried leaving `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on for the document view when adding it to the scroll view, and not setting constraints? The general rule is that when you hand off a view to another view or controller to place into the view hierarchy (other than with `addSubview:`, of course), then the recipient is responsible for turning off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and adding constraints as it desires. Similarly, notice that when creating a table view in IB, there aren't constraints on the table view (even after Add Missing Constraints).

Comment: Yes; I was fearing that was the situation. I thought not explicitly using Auto Layout ourselves meant the scroll view wouldn't be using constraints at all, and I assumed that would lead to issues mixing constraints and autoresizing masks in the same window. Things will probably be easier with autoresizing masks, yes...

Comment: Hmm? What makes you think you have to revert to using autoresizing masks?

Comment: Er, I meant I thought if I didn't use Auto Layout, the scroll view wouldn't either, and that *it* would use autoresizing masks instead. Maybe I'm misreading my own bugs for issues that happen when you mix and match?

Comment: The point is you don't know and you shouldn't care what the scroll view is using internally. That's why you have to take the most-backward-compatible approach (leaving `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on) when handing a view off to other code to incorporate into the view hierarchy. That other code may turn it off and set up constraints for itself or it may be ignorant of auto layout and leave it on and set up autoresizing masks. Either way, it's not your problem. You can continue to use auto layout for the rest of your view hierarchy, if you want.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I never thought of it that way ^^ I'll just revert all the auto layout stuff on the scroll view and hope that everything works out well and it was just me misremembering observations based on my own buggy code. Thanks!

Comment: The thing where if I resize the window small enough (or even if the initial size is small enough) the row 0 disappears under the header still happens even without Auto Layout. Is that a known issue?